# How to make my metronome play at the same time as recording in my program?

Tags: c, multithreading, function

This program is designed to be able to record and store melodies inputted by the user and then play back the sequences the user recorded. I'm trying to add a metronome in so that whilst you're recording you can hear the rhythmic pulse.

I've successfully made the tones as well as getting the function to work in time with the int length function. My problem is I can only get the metronome to play either before or after recording the sequence making the metronome pointless as you cant hear it whilst recording in the notes.

The fact that the function includes a while loop also stops the program from moving on to the next part of the program. I just want the metronome function to be active whilst recording.

Does anyone know how i can get it to play the metronome whilst recording rather than only being able to make it play the metronome either before or after starting the record function?

```
#include "aservelibs/aservelib.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
//------------------------------------------------function declarations
float mtof(int note, float frequency);
FILE play(void);
FILE record(void);
FILE record2(void);
int length();
void metronome(void);
//------------------------------------------------main program
int main()
{
//------------------------------------------------variables
    FILE *textFilePointer;
    FILE *textFilePointer2;
    int counter = 0;
    char user;


//------------------------------------------------main menu
    do

    {

        printf("Press A to Record 1st Melody (A), B to Record 2nd Melody (B)\nP to Play Melodies (P) X to Exit (X):");
        scanf(" %c", &user);
//------------------------------------------------record 1st melody
        if (user == 'a' || user == 'A')
        {

            textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");
            *textFilePointer = record();
            metronome();


            if(textFilePointer == NULL);
            {
                printf("Recording Complete\n");
                aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            counter = 0;
        }
//------------------------------------------------record 2nd melody
        else if (user == 'b' || user == 'B')
        {
            textFilePointer2 = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "w");
            *textFilePointer2 = record2();
            metronome();


            if(textFilePointer == NULL);
            {
                printf("Recording Complete\n");
                aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            counter = 0;
        }

//------------------------------------------------plays the melodies back
        else if (user == 'p' || user == 'P')
        {
            textFilePointer = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
            *textFilePointer = play();

            textFilePointer2 = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "r");
            *textFilePointer2 = play();

            if(textFilePointer == NULL);
            {
                printf("Playback Complete\n");
                aserveOscillator(0, 0, 0, 0);
                aserveOscillator(1, 0, 0, 0);

            }
            counter = 0;

        }
//-------------------------------------------------exits program
        else if (user == 'x' || user == 'X')
        {
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    while(counter < 16);
}
//--------------------------------------------------function declarations

//--------------------------------------------------converts MIDI number to frequency
float mtof(int note, float frequency)
{
    frequency = 440.0 * pow(2, (note-69) / 12.0);
    printf("Playing Note:%d\n", note);


    return frequency;
}
//--------------------------------------------------changes tempo of sequence playback
int length()
{

    return (aserveGetControl(7)/((127.0 - 0) / (1000 - 100))) + 100;
}
//--------------------------------------------------metronome function
void metronome(void)
{
    while(true)
    {
    aserveOscillator(3, 1500, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);

    aserveOscillator(3, 1000, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);

    aserveOscillator(3, 1000, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);

    aserveOscillator(3, 1000, 0.8, 0);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);
    aserveSleep(length()*2);
    aserveOscillator(3, 0, 0, 0);


    }
}
//--------------------------------------------------playback function
FILE play(void)
{
    FILE*file;
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "r");
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "r");

    do {

        int note[2];
        int velocity;
        float freq[2];
        int frequency;
        fscanf(file, "%d, %d\n", &note[0], &velocity);
        fscanf(file, "%d, %d\n", &note[1], &velocity);
        freq[0] = mtof(note[0], frequency);
        freq[1] = mtof(note[1], frequency);
        aserveOscillator(0, freq[0], 1.0, 0);
        aserveOscillator(1, freq[1], 1.0, 0);
        aserveSleep(length()*2);
    } while (feof(file) == 0);


    return *file;
}


//--------------------------------------------------layer 1 record function

FILE record(void)
{
    int counter;
    FILE*file;
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes1.txt", "w");

    do
    {

        int note = aserveGetNote();
        int velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
        if (velocity > 0)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%d, %d\n", note, velocity);
            printf("Note: %d, Velocity: %d\n", note, velocity);
            counter++;
        }


    } while (counter < 16);
    fclose(file);
    return *file;
}

//--------------------------------------------------layer 2 record function

FILE record2(void)
{
    int counter;
    FILE*file;
    file = fopen("/Users/Luke/Desktop/midinotes2.txt", "w");

    do
    {

        int note = aserveGetNote();
        int velocity = aserveGetVelocity();
        if (velocity > 0)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%d, %d\n", note, velocity);
            printf("Note: %d, Velocity: %d\n", note, velocity);
            counter++;
        }


    } while (counter < 16);
    fclose(file);
    return *file;
}
```

Comment: You should research the topic of threading. a thread for recording, and another for playing, is imho, the way to go.

Comment: @Henrik is it something i would be able to work out by thursday? its for an assignment. I've had a brief look online and it looks pretty confusing.. would you say its the only way? thanks for the response!

Comment: He he .. well.. In fact I wouldn't say it is the only way, you could have the loop in record2 play the metronome sound, at regular intervals, by checking time, but it is extremely tricky to get working if you dont want gaps in the recording..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to make threads:

```
#include <pthread.h>

void* metronome(void* param);

int playMetronome;

int main(){
    pthread_t tid1;

    playMetronome = 1;
    pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,metronome,0);

    //the code to record and play something

    playMetronome = 0; //the loop in metronome() stops at this point


    return 0;
}

void* metronome(void* param){
    while(playMetronome){
        //code to play metronome
        //this code will run simultaneous with the code to play melodies
   }

}
```

Comment: this is great! @moffetje thanks a lot for your help! It works, how would i make it so it only plays during the recording process rather than the whole program? Sorry for asking for more.. I have never come across threads before!

Comment: @LukeNicholls See my updated answer, you can accomplish this with a global variable.

Comment: thanks a lot, i found another way to do it using pthread_cancel(tid1) but your way definitely seems like a more sensible and cleaner way of doing it. Honestly im very grateful. You've helped me a great deal!

Comment: No problem! I remember being in your position last year, good luck!